# How to unescape an UTF-8 escaped byte array to an unescaped byte array without allocating a String

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core, utf-8

I have a `Span<byte>` representing an escaped string UTF-8 like:

Binary represention:
`byte[20] { 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 32, 92, 117, 50, 48, 97, 99, 32, 33 }`

Escaped represention:`"Hello world \u20ac !"`

Desired binary result:
`byte[17] {  72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 32, 226, 130, 172, 32, 33 }`

I tried  to transcode the escaped `\u20ac` by using the `GetString()` method:
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString())`

But this is not unescaping the input.

Is there any way to achieve to the same result ?

```
// Not working solution
public void NotWorkingUnescape(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source, Span<byte> destination)
{
    var tmp = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(source);
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp, destination);
}

// Unknown solution
// UTF-8 escaped byte array -> UTF8-8 unescaped byte array
public void FastUnescape(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source, Span<byte> destination)
{
    // ?
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it doesn't unescape anything. The result is the same as input.

Comment: You are right, I missed the point. Will update the question.

Comment: The solution may come from the JsonReader parser: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8fe5240a400898530a17f03b7ec544f54e538fcf/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/JsonReaderHelper.Unescaping.cs#L297

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a method that does all the work?

You could simply use this:

```
public void FastUnescape(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source, Span<byte> destination)
{
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(source), destination);
}
```

Or prevent any exception:

```
public void FastUnescape(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source, Span<byte> destination)
{
    if (source.Length <= destination.Length)
    {
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(source), destination);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

There is another way to do the conversion without using `Encoding.UTF8`, by seeing the @[JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337895/quickest-way-performance-wise-to-turn-a-string-into-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp) response you could implement the following:

```
public static void AnotherMethod(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source, Span<byte> destination)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = (byte) (Convert.ToChar(source[i]));
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when using [Convert.toChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=netframework-4.8), the conversion is done to an equivalent Unicode character no UTF-8 character, which is why `& 0x7f` is used in the post of the answer to obtain values in the ASCII range.

I did not do many tests in terms of performance or functionality with other special characters that you want to escape, however I have achieved the same results

Comment: Thanks for your code, but your solution is still allocating a `String`. 
My goal is to avoid this temporary allocation and manipulation.

Comment: That temporary value is the conversion, you will always have to do it when using the `GetBytes` method, I don't see another way, unless you use another totally different design. I have updated my answer

Comment: The updated solution looks fine for ASCII but, as you said, for UTF-8 this may not work as there is not 1-1 relationship